# Экспорт данных в Excel из listView

Tags: .net, winforms, c++-cli

[image: listVieWdata]

При нажатии на кнопку, надо экспортировать в Excel. Я нашел следующее:

```
private: System::Void button5_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
{
    ofstream outData;
    double A=10, B=20, C=7;   
    outData.open("SUN.csv", ios::app);
    for (int i=0; i<B; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<C; j++)
        {outData << A <<';';}
        outData << endl;
    }
    MessageBox::Show("Calendar saved. \nExcel file name: \"SUN.csv\" \nWay: Near SUN.exe file.", "File saved.", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Asterisk);
}
```

Вместо A мне надо задать содержимое в ячейке ListView, Вместо В надо задать кол-во строк, а вместо С кол-во столбцов в ListView.
Помогите правильно заполнить А, В и С.